# Meaning of “the first year it has featured anywhere on the list”

Tags: meaning

I read in an article in the Daily Mail listing the most violent cities in the world. The article had a picture caption which says:

> Los Cabos, in Mexico, was ranked as the most violent city in the world, **the first year it has featured anywhere on the list**
>
> <sup>Sounce: [Daily Mail news article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5481483/42-worlds-50-violent-cities-South-America.html#ixzz59GX63khg)</sup>

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of “the first year it has featured anywhere on the list”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[feature](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feature)** (v): *Have as a prominent attribute or aspect; Be a significant characteristic of or take an important part in.*

The sentence says that Los Cabos now *prominently appears* at the top of the list of most violent cities in the world.  This is unusual because, in past years, it wasn't even on the list (it "didn't *feature* anywhere on the list")

Related examples:

> This is the first time in thirty years that the TV network **has featured** this program as part of their regular schedule.
>
> The designer came from nowhere and now her work **features** among the most popular fashions this year.

Answer (score 3):

From the URL, the article is talking about a list of the 50 most violent cities. Presumably this list is updated annually, with cities moving on and off the list from year to year as they get more or less dangerous.  The further implication is that the violence being tabulated is for the current year (or the most recent year for which statistics are available).

The is **the first year** that Los Cabos, Mexico, is **anywhere on the list**, meaning that last year (and all other years previously) it was not one of the 50 most violent cities.  That is, in years prior to this one, it was at worst the 51st most violent city.

The article is mentioning this to emphasize a very sudden and large increase in violence.  Last year, Los Cabos was safer than at least the 50 cities that made last year's list.  This year, violence is so bad there that it jumped ahead of all 50 of those cities all the way to the most violent city spot.

Answer (score 2):

Within the context of the article **The 50 most dangerous cities in the world**

Means that in previous years the city **Los Cabos** hasn't been in the top 50 and therefore not on the list.

However, this year, is the first time it has appeared on the list.

It's even more extraordinary that, according to the article, that it is **the most violent city in the world** and has gone straight to the top.